# How to do these Geometry proofs using vectors?

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, problem-solving

I'm new to vectors and need to answer the following two things:

1. Show by using vectors that the mid segment of a trapezoid is parallel to the bases and $1/2$ as long as the sum of them.

That's what I got so far.
[image]

2. Show by using vectors that the line segment m in a quadrilateral is equal to the sum of both not divided side-vectors divided by two.
   [image]

The work sheet only provides the solutions but I can't figure out how to get there.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you start by assigning position vectors to vertices? Then you can figure out the vectors for midpoints and proceed. Please avoid no-clue questions and show your work properly.

Comment: Yes, I updated the pics, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: That is not the correct way to label. Please assume position vectors of vertices A, B, C and D as $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}, \vec{d}$.

Comment: Then what is the position vector of $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Answer (score 1):

We do not work with *free vectors*. We work with *position vectors*, which are fixed on the Euclidean plane wrt some origin. (See figure.) The underlying coordinate plane provides coordinates to any points $P,Q$. This facilitates writing $\vec{OP}=P-O$ and $\vec{PQ}=Q-P$. For example if $P=(3,4)$ on coordinate plane, then $\vec{OP}=(3-0,4-0)=3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}$.

[image]

So let *position vectors* of the vertices of trapezium be $A,B,C,D$. Since $E$ is midpoint of $AD$, its position vector will be (think coordinates)
$$E=\frac{A+D}{2} \, , \quad F=\frac{B+C}{2}$$

Now lengths are given by magnitudes of vectors
$$|AB|=|\vec{AB}|=B-A \, , \quad |DC|=|\vec{DC}|=C-D$$

Since $AB // DC$, $\,\vec{DC}=k\vec{AB}$.

Now $$|EF|=F-E=\frac{(B-A)+(C-D)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(|AB|+|DC|)$$

You can also conclude about parallelism.

This was Ques $1$. Now you can do Ques $2$.